# How to upload static image to database using php?

Tags: php, database, blob, qr-code

I know how to upload image using form

```
    <input type="file" >
```

But I want to add the same file at every new record as that file is being edited by the QRphpLibrary. So every time a new record is entered through a form. It  creates a file test2.png in the same folder. 
My database is

**Image( id int , QR BLOB ) **

So how can i add image without (using form and taking filename input from user). User has no idea about the image. It is generated By QRPHPLibrary

Answer (score 0):

Try looking into triggers. Its a stored procedure that creates an action every time you add something to your database.